# Задача о паркете

Tags: java, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Помогите исправить код программы, которая по идее должна решать следующую задачу:

Собственно сама задача:
Комнату размером n*m единиц требуется покрыть одинаковыми плитками паркета размером 2*1 единиц без пропусков и наложений (m<=20, n<=8, m,n -целые). Пол можно покрыть паркетом различными способами. Требуется определить количество всех возможных способов укладки паркета для конкретных значений m<=20, n<=8. Результатом задачи является таблица, содержащая 20 строк и 8 столбцов.Элементом таблицы является число, являющееся решением задачи для соответствующих n и m.

Ссылки на объяснение решения:
[Окулов Программирование в Алгоритмах стр. 120](ftp://icf.bofh.ru/pub/docs/linux-support/programming/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A1.%D0%9C.%20-%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85.pdf)

И код:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main {

    //Временная, для вычислений
    static BigInteger[][] B = new BigInteger[256][21];
    //Результирующая таблица
    static BigInteger[][] A = new BigInteger[9][21];

    //Вычисляет k - ю степень 2
    public static long St2(int k) {
        if (k <= 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (long) Math.pow(2, k);
        }
    }

    //{k,l -номера сечений, pi - количество анализируемых разрядов сечений}
    public static boolean Can(int k, int l, int pi) {
        int i;
        long d;
        boolean b, res;
        res = false;
        b = false;
        for (i = 1; i <= pi; i++) {
            d = St2(i);
            if ((k & d) == 0){ //{определяется значение разряда с номером d для сечения k}
                if ((l & d) == 0) {//если d-тый разряд 1-го сечения - 0, сравнивается d-тый разряд 2-го сечения
                    b = !b; /**если d-тый разряд первого и второго сечения = 0, значение b меняется на противоположное, затем
                            *чтобы при нечетном количестве нулей выбивало из метода с результатом false
                            */
                } else { // kd = 0, ld = 1
                    if (b) { // если b = true
                        return false; // завершение метода - false, срабатывает в случаях когда количество 0 перед 1 нечетно
                        /**
                         * Метод завершается с результатом false в случаях
                         *  d = 00 || l = 10 - корректно
                         *  d = 0000 || l = 1000 - корректно
                         *
                         */
                    }
                }
            } else if (((l & d) != 0) || b) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        ;
        res = !b;
        return res;
    }

    //Основная логика
    public static void Solve() {
        int i, j, k, l;
        long max;
        //Цикл по значению длины комнаты
        for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            max = St2(i) - 1;
            B[0][0] = BigInteger.ONE;
            //Цикл по значению ширины комнаты
            for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++) { //цикл для обсепечения всей ширины комнаты сечениями
                //Сечение с номером k
                for (k = 0; k <= max; k++) {
                    //Сечение с номером l
                    for (l = 0; l <= max; l++) //if (Can(k,l,i))
                    {
                        //Проверка совместимости сечений
                        boolean r = Can(k, l, i);
                        if (r) {
                            B[k][j] = B[k][j].add(B[l][j - 1]);

                        }
                    }
                }
                A[i][j] = B[0][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //забиваем нулями таблицы
        for (int m = 0; m <= 20; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n <= 8; n++) {
                A[n][m] = BigInteger.ZERO;
            }
        }
        for (int m = 0; m <= 20; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n <= 255; n++) {
                B[n][m] = BigInteger.ZERO;
            }
        }
        //производим расчет
        Solve();

        //выводим результаты
        for (int m = 1; m <= 20; m++) {
            for (int n = 1; n <= 8; n++) {

                if (n * m % 2 != 0) {
                    String val="*";
                    for(int p=0;p<25;p++)
                        val+=" ";
                    System.out.print(val);
                } else
                if (m == 1 && n % 2 == 0) {
                    String val="1";
                    for(int p=0;p<25;p++)
                        val+=" ";
                    System.out.print(val);
                } else {
                    String val=A[n][m].toString();
                    int v=val.length();
                    for(int p=0;p<26-v;p++)
                        val+=" ";
                    System.out.print(val);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Не корректно работает потому как: при m либо n = 2, количество способов укладки плиток - это последовательность Фибоначчи, программа выдает нечто иное. + метод Can(0, 3, 4) т.е. для сечений 0 и 3 и при длине пола 4(количество разрядов int-сечений в двоичном представлении) возвращает false, хотя очевидно должна быть true

Answer (score 4):

У вас есть серьёзная ошибка в логике:

```
 for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        max = St2(i) - 1;
             ....
             Can(... i);
```

Вы тут делаете цикл по ширине комнаты (давайте договоримся, то что меньше 8, то и ширина). При этом этот цикл не нужен вообще для вычисления на конкретной ширине. Если вы хотите получить ответы для разных значений ширины, то делать это надо в другом массиве. Быстрая правка - зафиксировать i = N. Длинная арифметика вам здесь не нужна, максимальный ответ (для 8*20) будет `3547073578562247994` что вполне влазит в `long`. Зато затрудняет чтение. Дальше нумеровать биты всё же нужно с 1 (метод `can`):

```
  for (i = 1; i <= pi; i++) {
        d = St2(i);
```

Что даёт неверный ответ.

Кстати, где у вас проверка что маски не пересекаются? `if (((l & d) != 0) || b)` тут проверять `b` не надо..

Степени 2 вычислять через Math.pow режет глаза, есть же битовый сдвиг.

В общем сидеть тут с отладчиком можно долго. Вот моё решение написанное на коленке.

```
long long Res[21][256];
char goodMask[256];
int pow2[8];

int N = 8,M = 20;

bool good(int mask){
    int pos = N-1;
    while (pos >= 0)
        if ( ~mask& pow2[pos] )
            if (!pos)
                return 0;
            else if (mask& pow2[pos - 1])
                return 0;
                else pos-=2;
        else pos--;
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        pow2[i] = 1<<i;
    int border = (1 << N);
    for (int i=0;i<border;i++)
        goodMask[i] = good(i);
    Res[0][0] = 1;
    for (int pos = 0; pos <M; pos++)
        for (int i=0;i<border;i++) //Left Mask
            for (int j=0;j<border;j++)//Right Mask
                if ( !(i&j)) //no intersect
                    if (goodMask[i|j])
                       Res[pos+1][j]+=Res[pos][i];

    for (int i=0;i<=M;i++)
            cout << Res[i][0]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Думаю имея это дописать ваше решение будет несложно.

Comment: "будет несложно" - не знаком с С++. Попробую разобраться, делать нечего. Насчет "нумеровать биты с 1" и Math.pow согласен.

Comment: if (((l & d) != 0) || b) - здесь проверка на отсутствие таких 101 конструкций

Comment: @Serg4356 если они пересекаются, то проверять на b не надо. Уже нельзя.

Comment: можете пояснить? а то не поспеваю

Comment: @Serg4356 у меня вопрос сначала) а что у вас единица в маске значит, вы можете сформулировать?

Comment: Разряд в сечениях, корректность которого проверяем

Comment: @Serg4356 не нравится мне слово разряд... Если проще - если там единица, то в этой клетке заканчивается домино. В 2 соседених они же никак не могут заканчиваться одноврменно, так же.

Comment: @Serg4356 понятнее стало? Если есть вопросы, задавайте.

Comment: Насчет стоящих рядом единиц в сечениях это понятно, "|| b" как мне казалось тут для таких ситуаций k = 101, l = 000. Хотя сейчас сомневаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Оставил попытки доработать чужой код, вместо этого мой:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parquet{

    // метод для сопоставления сечений
    public static boolean acceptCut(int firstCut, int secondCut, int digitsCount){
        int countSecond = 0;// переменная для хранения кол-ва 0 во втором сечении

        for(int i=0;i<digitsCount;i++){//цикл по каждому разряду сечения
            int digit = (1<<i);// маска
            if((firstCut&digit)==0) {//если i-ый разряд 1-го сечения =0
                    if ((secondCut & digit) == 0) {//если i-ый разряд 2-го сечения =0
                        countSecond++;
                        } else {//если i-ый разряд 2-го сечения !=0
                            if(countSecond%2!=0) return false;// и кол-во 0 во втором сечении - нечетно
                        }
                } else {//если i-ый разряд 1-го сечения !=0
                    if ((secondCut & digit)!=0) return false; // (countSecond%2!=0)|| и кол-во 0 во втором сечении - нечетно
                }
            }
            if((countSecond%2!=0)) return false;//(countFirst%2!=0)||
        return true;
    }

    //метод для нахождения решений для заданных m n
    public static String countValues(int digitsCount, int roomWidth){
    ArrayList resArray = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList resArray2 = new ArrayList();
        String res ="0", res2="";
    long resNumber = 0;
    int maxi = 1<<digitsCount;
    int maxy= 1<<digitsCount;

    if(digitsCount*roomWidth%2!=0) return "*";

    //устанавливаем первоначальные значания для resArray
    resArray.add(0);
    //используем значения из resArray перебираем подходящие
  outer: for(int i=0; i<roomWidth;i++) {
         for (int x = 0; x < maxy; x++) {//resArray.size()     res.length()  тут использую лист для сохранения подходящих значений, так по крайней мере работает

             if (i == (roomWidth - 1)) maxi = 1;

             for (int z = 0; z < maxi; z++) {
                 if (acceptCut(x, z, digitsCount)) {//(Integer) resArray.get(x) |||| acceptCut(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(res.charAt(x)))
                     System.out.println(x + "|" + fullString(x, digitsCount)
                      + "|" + z + "|" + fullString(z, digitsCount) );
/**
                     resArray2.add(z);
                     res2 += z;
                      */
                     if (i == (roomWidth - 1)) {
                         resNumber++;
                     }
                 }
             }
             if(i==0) continue outer;
         }
         /**
          resArray.clear();
          for (int x = 0; x < resArray2.size(); x++) {
          resArray.add(resArray2.get(x));
          }
          resArray2.clear();


         res = res2;
         res2 = "";
        */
     }
    return Long.toString(resNumber);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

     // System.out.println(fullString(3,4));
        /**
        for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
            System.out.println(countValues(i, 2) + "|" + countValues(2, i) + "|");
        }
*/
  //    System.out.println(countValues(3,2));

        System.out.println(acceptCut(2,0,3));
        System.out.println(acceptCut(0,2,3));

    }
}
```

В чем минусы: использование ArrayList явно не лучшее решение. При попытке использовать на максимальных значениях (8,20) ошибка: Java heap space.
Почему выбрал такой путь - чтобы сохранять значения правого(если сравнивать слева направо) сечения а затем подставлять в левые т.к. не понимаю можно ли задать алгоритм для их нахождения. Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем методе acceptCut() стоит проверка на нечетное последовательное кол-во пар нулей. Так вот 3-е сечение (на рисунке) как раз не укладывается в логику, т.е. оно может сгенерироваться в переборе в любом месте, но по факту возникнуть может только после 2-го сечения - поэтому я посчитал правильным решения сохранять. В целом вроде как и работает если использовать Arraylist, но это не точно (проверял на длину/ширину 2 - последовательность Фибоначчи получается). Но если логикой и перебором то возникают такие ситуации acceptCut(2,0,3) = true, a acceptCut(0,2,3) = false

Comment: @pavel можете посмотреть?